# Matplotlib 3d barplot failing to draw just one face

Tags: matplotlib

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.array([[x, y] for x in range(5) for y in range(x+1)]).T
z = 1/ (5*x + 5)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection = '3d')

ax.bar3d(x, y, np.zeros_like(z), dx = 1, dy = 1, dz = z)
```

yields

[image]

How do I get the face at (1,0) to display properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no good solution to this. Fortunately though, it happens only for some viewing angles. So you can choose an angle where it plots fine, e.g.

```
ax.view_init(azim=-60, elev=25)
```

[image]